# Touchesbegan and touchesmoved functions not working on UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I am having these 2 functions in my FYImageSequence.m file.I inherited the class from UIImageView

```
@interface FVImageSequence : UIImageView
```

I was able to connect this to my UIImageView in storyboard.But how to make the functions below working.Is there any connections that should be done.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
if(increment == 0)
    increment = 1;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    previous = touchLocation.x;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
int location = touchLocation.x;

if(location < previous)
    current += increment;
else
    current -= increment;

previous = location;

if(current > numberOfImages)
    current = 0;
if(current < 0)
    current = numberOfImages;

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", prefix, current];
NSLog(@"%@", path);

path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:extension];


UIImage *img =  [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

[self setImage:img];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

User interaction of `UIImageView` is by default **NO**. So you need to make it **YES** like this

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `UserInteractionEnabled` to `YES` on the image view.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I had to use the method, and not the variable (somehow the variable was not accessible directly), so:
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];